# can ssis pick up the file with the latest date creation?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I am thinking of using ssis reading excel files in the folder.

The folder is updated daily by putting new file in without deleting any old files.

I am now using a 'for each' container to loop all the files and loading them into a consolidated table.

However, the boss only wants the latest file to be loaded into the table and he does not want a incremental table.

Can ssis check the file creation date using some functions in ssis and only load the latest one?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: "I am thinking of using ssis reading excel files in the folder" - that would be your first mistake! Every time I mistakenly have that thought, sanity prevails and I do it in C# (pick a language that it not SSIS)

Comment: @MitchWheat I disagree. There are definitely occasions when SSIS is the right tool for the job, depending on the structure of the spreadsheet. If the structure is simple then SSIS is ok. Otherwise I agree that C# and the OpenXML SDK is a better approach.

Comment: @Greg: Everytime I think "It's a multiple excel files in folder read. I know! I'll use SSIS." Everytime I regret it. You make a single change to the package and you end up reconfiguring it. It's insane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ou can use this script:

      public void Main()
         {

      // TODO: Add your code here
             var directory= new DirectoryInfo(Dts.Variables["User::VarFolderPath"].Value.ToString());

            FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();
            DateTime lastModified = DateTime.MinValue;

             foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                if (file.LastWriteTime > lastModified)
                {
                    lastModified = file.LastWriteTime;
                    Dts.Variables["User::VarFileName"].Value = file.ToString();
                }
            }

             MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["User::VarFileName"].Value.ToString());


             Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
         }
```

also you can cgeck this link below:

```
http://sqlage.blogspot.in/2013/12/ssis-how-to-get-most-recent-file-from.html
```