# ssis flat file creation date

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a very simple ssis task, currently it is just a flat file connection and a bulk insert task to update a table. I cannot figure out how to ensure the flat file was created today before continuing with the bulk insert.

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161004/can-ssis-pick-up-the-file-with-the-latest-date-creation

Comment: Thank you that solution will work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Data Flow block, add a Script component, like this:

[image]

Add two variables, one for your file name and one for the result of the script:
[image]

Next, configure your script as follows:

[image]

Now, you can add the following expression to the arrow between the script component and your data flow block:

[image]

Your code in the script itself would be:

```
public void Main()
    {
        string fileName = Dts.Variables["FileName"].Value.ToString();
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);

        Dts.Variables["FileWasCreatedToday"].Value = fi.CreationTime >= DateTime.Now.Date;

        // Another option would be to set this to fail if it's not created today. This will fail the whole package.
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

**Edit:** If you want it to send you an email in the case of a failure, just create a second link from the Script Task to your Send Mail Task with the following expression: `!@[User::FileWasCreatedToday]`. Like below:

[image]

Comment: I have tried this solution but I notice if I set the task to fail it does not move on to the next step, which is a send email task to warn me of the failure.

Comment: @user2369812 You don't need to set it to fail - just conditionally either move to the data flow task or the task to email you based on the `FileWasCreatedToday` variable. (See my update).

Comment: @user2369812 Glad I could help.